# Long names file's in 7z command line

Tags: php, command-line, 7zip

I use `system` for run 7z command line in PHP and this sees as

```
echo system("7z a $file -tzip $http_file 2>&1");
```

But because `$http_file = 'File abra cadabra.txt'` (filename has spaces), I got an error

**Command Line Error: Unknown switch: - -**
How to be with long names?

I added quote around `$file` and `$http_file`, but got the same result.

Comment: Put a quotes around: `echo system("7z a $file -tzip '$http_file' 2>&1");`

Comment: I would put quotes also around $file, just for the future.

Comment: Ignore the advice in the comments here, use `escapeshellarg` which handles all of this for you, including backslashes and quotes that normally cause problems. http://php.net/escapeshellarg